# nullSafeGet in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate

I am upgrading Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4.1. When running the application, I got below exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2701)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1541)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1473)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1373)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:640)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2042)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3710)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:439)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:420)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:992)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:919)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:610)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:150)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:995)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:874)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2292)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2255)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
        at my.com.MyDAOImpl.findDocuments(MyDaoImpl.java:22)......
```

I understand Hibernate4 changed parameters in `nullSafeGet()` and `nullSafeSet()`. So I have to override these methods using new parameters and ignored SessionImplementor in customized type implemetation anyway.

`findDocuments()` basically query documents from Documents table, none of the fields of `Document.hmb.xml` has customized type. My puzzle is why `CustomType.nullSafeGet()` is called? In Document.hmb.xml, there is only one suspect but I am not sure at the moment as after I changed the type to "Blob" and got same error.

```
  <property name="image" column="PICTURE" type="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType"/>
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is resolved by changing "`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType` to "`materialized_blob`.

```
<property name="image" column="PICTURE" type="materialized_blob"/>
```

It looks like Spring implemenation calls `Hibernate 3 CustomType.java` which conflicts with the `Hibernate 4 CustomType.java`. One lesson learned, when upgrading Hibernate 3 to 4, blob column needs to use "`materialized_blob`" as type, which is much simpler solution than Hibernate 3, Spring has to put a `lobHandler` inside sessionFactory.

Comment: If you switch from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4, you should also switch to a version of Spring that supports Hibernate 4, otherwise you can get unexpected errors like these. Check the documentation of the version of Spring that you are using.

Comment: I am also upgrading spring from 2.5.4 to 3.2. Yes, so many unexpected errors are happening at the moment. Thanks for yr suggestion.